# HashMap and Java Bean list as datasource in Jasper report

Tags: java, jasper-reports, javabeans

My Jasper report has some fields for which I am passing the value through HashMap using datasource as `JRMapCollectionDataSource`. Now there is another requirement to add table to this report.

This table will be populated with Java bean list. The problem is how to pass both of these different datasources to jasper repot.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Collection<Map<String, ?>> col = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, YYYY");
    Date date = new Date();
    String format = dateFormat.format(date);
    parameters.put("date", format);
    parameters.put("sDate", new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-YYYY").format(date));
    parameters.put("participantName", "test user");

    col.add(parameters);

    TestBean bean = new TestBean();
    bean.setA("a");
    bean.setB("a");
    bean.setC("a");
    bean.setD("a");

    List<TestBean> collection =new ArrayList<>();
    collection.add(bean);

    // need to send bean object to jasper report to populate table


    try {

        JasperReport compileReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("C:/test/development/jasper_reports/report1.jrxml");
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(compileReport, parameters, new  JRMapCollectionDataSource(col));

        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint,"C:/test/development/jasper_reports/report1.pdf");
    } catch (JRException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

Please suggest a solution or alternative method to follow.

Thanks,
Hanumant

Comment: Did you try to use subreports ?
http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/subreports-jaspersoft-studio

Comment: @AlanNeves, thanks for you suggestion. But the project was scrapped and hence any work related to Jasper